# readFileSync: Why only first character of string being returned?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

Why does the code only return the first character of the string?

Text for the first 6 rows is:

1-800-FLOWERS.COM, INC.

1ST SOURCE

1ST SOURCE CORP

3D SYSTEMS

8X8, INC.

A.H. BELO

Have reviewed every post here related to the same issue, none directly provide a solution.

```
    const searchkeywords = fs.readFileSync('kwords.csv','utf-8');
        for (let kword of searchkeywords) {
    console.log(`Search Keyword: ${kword}`);
```

Hoping a solution to retrieve the entire row text string from the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Found simple answer, parse.

```
function readKeyWords(path) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
        .split('\n');
}
```

then

```
    const searchkeywords = readKeyWords('kwords.csv','utf-8');    
    for (let kword of searchkeywords) {     
    console.log(`Search Keyword: (${kword})`);
```

for anyone whom has the same question.